# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Curso as array in

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo

Hola tengo esta función que me saca un array pero cuando intento por ejemplo obtener el nombre de la siguiente forma curso[0]['nombre'] me dice que no se puede utilizar el objeto de tipo Curso como matriz.

```
public function mostrarCurso(){
    $db = BaseDatos::conectar();
    $listadoCurso = [];

    $select = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Curso');
    /*Si no están los setters no se mostrarán en la tabla*/
    foreach ($select->fetchAll() as $curso) {
    // foreach ($select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $curso) {
        $myCurso = new Curso();
        $myCurso->setIdCurso($curso['id_curso']);
        $myCurso->setNombreCurso($curso['nombre']);
        $myCurso->setCantAlumnos($curso['cant_alumnos']);
        $myCurso->setFechaInicio($curso['fecha_inicio']);
        $myCurso->setFechaFin($curso['fecha_fin']);
        $myCurso->setNivelCurso($curso['nivel_curso']);
        $myCurso->setFoto($curso['foto']);
        $myCurso->setEstadoCurso($curso['estado']);
        $listadoCurso[] = $myCurso;
    }
    return $listadoCurso;
}
```

Comment: ese error es del foreach estas tratando esa query como objeto en vez de tratarlo como array, te recomiendo que hagas un `echo` al select antes de recorrerlo para ver que trae o un `print_r`

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por su interés. Al final encontre una solución y es hacer un json_decode(json_encode($curso)); de esta forma consigo sacar un array y ya poder tratarlo.

Comment: que bueno que te funcionó.

Comment: @sergibarca, por favor publique la respuesta y acepte su propia respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que lo que estaba pasando eran objetos, lo que hago es json_decode(json_decode()) para generar un Array.

```
$curso = json_decode(json_encode($crudCurso->mostrar()), true);
```

Y de esta forma ya podré recuperar los datos de la siguiente manera,

```
$curso['nameCurso'];
```